# Rewriting higher powers in $K[x]/(p)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Suppose $p = \sum a_i x^i \in K[x]$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ over some field $K$. Assume WLOG that $a_n = -1$, so we can rewrite the equation $p = 0$ as

$$x^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i x^i$$

Working now in the ring $K[x]/(p)$, this equation allows us to rewrite higher powers $x^m$, $m \geq n$ uniquely as a linear combination of $1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^{n-1}$, i.e. a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$. Is an explicit formula known for this representation? I worked out (might be some mistakes):

$$ x^{n+1} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (a_{i-1} + a_{n-1}a_i) x^i $$

$$ x^{n+2} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \big( a_{i-2} + a_{n-1} a_{i-1} + (a_{n-2} + a_{n-1}^2)a_i \big) x^i $$

but couldn't see an obvious pattern to prove inductively.

---

More generally, it seems that for any $p \in K[x]$ of degree $n$, $K[x]/(p)$ is canonically $K$-vector space of dimension $n$, having a canonical basis $\{ 1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^{n-1} \}$. Here, the "multiplication by $x$ map" $q \mapsto xq$ seems to be an interesting linear map - is anything known about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the linear transformation $q \mapsto xq$ is the so-called "[companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)" of $p$, which looks like

$$
\left( \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & a_0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & a_1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & a_2 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & a_3 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & a_{n-1}
\end{matrix} \right)
$$

An explicit formula for the powers of the companion matrix is given in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379595901639), from which you can extract an explicit formula for the $x^m$ in $K[x]/(p)$. It's not pretty though.